# Firebug close button

Tags: firebug

Is there an easy way to hide/disabled or change meaning of "close" button in **Firebug 1.5**? I am talking about **"power like" button** in top-right corner of Firebug window.

I have a "small" problem with this button because I constantly hit it when I want to minimize Firebug window. But it disables the Fb window as well. I know there is a minimize button on the left, by for some reason (maybe that is how it worked in previous versions) I treat this "power off" button as minimize button and I can't (and don't want :) to get rid of that habit.

Is there any way to change the behaviour of this buttons so it works as I would like it (**minimizing instead of disabling**)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to Ruth's suggestion, if you navigate to:

C:\Documents and Settings\\ApplicationData\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\.default\extensions\firebug@software.joehewitt\content\firebug

And open firebug.js, you should be able to find the following function:

```
closeFirebug: function(userCommand)  // this is really deactivate
{
    var browser = FirebugChrome.getCurrentBrowser();

    TabWatcher.unwatchBrowser(browser, userCommand);
    Firebug.resetTooltip();
},
```

Simply change this to:

```
closeFirebug: function(userCommand)  // this is really deactivate
{
    Firebug.toggleBar(false);
},
```

... now clicking the deactivate (close) button will simply minimize the Firebug panel.

Comment: This is it. Works like a charm. Thanks to Ruth for showing the right direction.

Comment: Seconded - chances are I wouldn't have found the source without the heads-up.  Cheers Ruth :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll find the firebug source code in

C:\Documents and settings\username\ApplicationData\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\randomChars.default\extensions\

From in here you'll be able to change the action of the close button

Comment: I forgot to mention the code is in a folder called firebug@software.joehewitt or something like that, in the Extensions Folder

Comment: and finally, if you're worried about changing the source\breaking your current install, you can check the source out again from here http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/checkout